# ClassNotFoundException but nothing wrong

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-mvc, classnotfoundexception

I am trying to run a ControllerClassNameHandlerMapping sample from mkyong.

I imported the project into eclipse and kicked off tomcat 6.0, but got this exception. I looked at several spots which are easily missed, but found nothing...

Here is the code

web.xml:

```
<web-app id="WebApp_ID" version="2.4" 
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee 
http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">

    <display-name>Spring Web MVC Application</display-name>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.htm</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml</param-value>
   </context-param>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>
             org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
        </listener-class>
    </listener>

</web-app>
```

mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd">

    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.ControllerClassNameHandlerMapping">
        <property name="caseSensitive" value="true" />
        <property name="pathPrefix" value="/customer" />
    </bean>

    <bean class="com.mkyong.common.controller.WelcomeController" />
    <bean class="com.mkyong.common.controller.HelloGuestController" />

    <bean id="viewResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver" >
            <property name="prefix">
                <value>/WEB-INF/pages/</value>
            </property>
            <property name="suffix">
                <value>.jsp</value>
            </property>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

directory structure:

![enter image description here][1]

HelloGuestController:

```
package com.mkyong.common.controller;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.AbstractController;

public class HelloGuestController extends AbstractController{

    @Override
    protected ModelAndView handleRequestInternal(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {

        ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("HelloWorldPage");
        model.addObject("msg", "HelloGuestController");

        return model;
    }

}
```

WelcomeController:

```
package com.mkyong.common.controller;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.AbstractController;

public class WelcomeController extends AbstractController{

    @Override
    protected ModelAndView handleRequestInternal(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {

        ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("HelloWorldPage");
        model.addObject("msg", "WelcomeController");

        return model;
    }

}
```

Exception notice:

Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mkyong.common.controller.WelcomeController

Comment: This generally means your class is not making it into your classpath.  Make sure all your generated jars are referenced in your classpath.

Also, don't post a bunch of images of your code.  Instead, copy and paste the actual code and use the `{}` button in the code dialog to format it as code

Comment: Which class is not found?

Comment: Please post your exact entire exception.

Comment: WelcomeController can't be found... @Moritz Petersen

Comment: Perhaps that link from mkyong.com can help you http://www.mkyong.com/spring/spring-error-classnotfoundexception-org-springframework-web-context-contextloaderlistener/

Answer (score 0):

I can think of these two possibilities:

- Check your build/classes folder. Does it have the class file for "WelcomeController" in the appropriate package.
- If you are using MAVEN, have you added "Maven Dependencies" to the project's "Web Deployment Assembly". If not, add that as follows (assuming you are using Eclipse):
  Right Click on your project -> Properties -> Deployment Assembly -> Add -> Java Build Path Entries -> Next and then from there you can add "maven Dependencies". Then build and try to run your app.

Comment: I checked maven dependencies and there they are. One thing very interesting is that I keep the project as it is and import the project into another version of eclipse(Helio), it works... Before I used maven 2 and juno